# Jquery Header Selection based on inbuilt CSS class .ui-accordion-header

Tags: jquery, css, accordion, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to select all headers presents in my accordion with the help of inbuilt css class and trying to disable each header using below statement.

```
  $('.ui-accordion-header').attr('disabled', true);
```

It works fine in IE9 but starts giving Script errors when tried in IE 7. I am using 
jquery-1.7.1.min.js & jquery-ui-1.8.17 version of Jquery UI.

Basic intent is to disable navigation to next Panes from current active pane on click of its Header since I have controls inside each pane to control the navigation to next panes.

Once next panes are open users can go to previous panes and current pane but not to next panes.

Error Scrernshot[image]

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // on page ready first init of your accordion
            $('#accordion').accordion(
                {
                    autoHeight: false,
                    animated: true,
                    collapsible: true
                });

            $('.ui-accordion-header').attr('disabled', true);

        });
    </script>
```

I was able to put a debugger and found out error within jquery framework. Its breaking only in IE7, for IE 9 I dont get any such errors.
[image]

Comment: what script errors does it give? what happens if you swap .attr for .prop?

Comment: I see no reason that this would fail even in IE7. What errors?

Comment: Script errors may be have to do with some other code, above code looks fine for all browsers

Comment: Chimioo - It just says: An error has occurred in the script on this page. Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?

Comment: Manoj, I tried commenting this line and tried in both IE7 and IE 9 everything works fine, but once I add it back it starts giving script error in IE 7 but not in IE 9..

Comment: You should be able to see the actual error it's giving if you use F12 in IE10 and select IE7 mode

Comment: Also,$('.ui-accordion-header').length
returns correct value but


$('.ui-accordion-header').each(function(){$(this).attr("disabled",true);});
or


$('.ui-accordion-header').each(function(){$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");});
 
fails.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't think `true` is a valid value for `disabled`. Try setting `disabled` to "disabled" as in XHTML, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a work around to solve this issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // on page ready first init of your accordion
            $('#accordion').accordion(
                {
                    autoHeight: false,
                    animated: true,
                    collapsible: true,
                    changestart : function(event,ui){
                         ui.newHeader.attr("disabled",false);
                    },
                    create: function (event, ui) {
                    $('.ui-accodrion-header').attr("disabled", true);
                }
                });
    });
</script>
```

This works perfectly...

Mentioning this if anyone faces this issue again.